# Casos de uso para jogo de adivinhar cor

Tags: engenharia-de-software, uml, diagrama, casos-de-uso

A fim de praticar APOO estou tentando aplicar casos de uso a um simples jogo de adivinhar uma cor.

Aqui seria ele visualmente. O usuário pode tentar adivinhar quantas vezes quiser, ou reiniciar o jogo clicando em *"Reset"*.

[image: Adivinhe a cor]

Apesar de simples, parece que cabem três casos de uso aqui:

#### Iniciar jogo

1. Jogo secretamente escolhe uma cor aleatória dentre três disponíveis.
2. Jogo exibe cor neutra (cinza).

#### Jogar jogo

Pré-condição: jogo iniciado

1. Jogador escolhe uma cor dentre três disponíveis.
2. Jogo exibe cor escolhida.
3. Se cor igual à oculta, informa que o jogador venceu.
4. Se cor diferente da oculta, informa que o jogador perdeu.
5. Jogador pode repetir a jogada (passo 1) quantas vezes quiser.

#### Reiniciar jogo

1. Jogador solicita início de novo jogo.
2. Caso de uso **Iniciar Jogo** fica disponível.

Tenho três dúvidas:

- Os casos de uso estão bem (corretamente) definidos?
- Jogador é um ator (externo ao sistema); jogo também é um ator? Como fica o diagrama de casos de uso nesse caso (ficaria um ator dentro dos limites do sistema, por exemplo)?
- Em **Reiniciar jogo**, outro caso de uso é chamado. Na verdade esse caso de uso precisa ser chamado toda vez que a aplicação iniciar. Como represento isso no diagrama de casos de uso? Ou isso não está correto (deveria ser somente uma pré-condição, por exemplo)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Não, não estão bem definidos. O sistema [não deve ser seu próprio ator](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/272316/93338). O jogador faz sentido ser ator e seus dois casos de uso estão corretos, trazem algo de valor para o mesmo: jogar jogo e reiniciar jogo.
2. e 3. O caso de uso iniciar jogo não faz sentido. Deveria ser uma [constraint](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/356441/93338)  (uma pré-condição) dos outros dois casos de uso.